# Multiple JOIN in Linq-to-SQL

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to do the following query in linq-to-sql (joining 3 different tables):

```
select * from tbl_round r 
inner join tbl_election e on r.fk_election_id = e.election_id
inner join tbl_meeting m on m.meeting_id = e.fk_meeting_id
```

Here is what I have so far but not correct:

```
from round in db.tbl_rounds
join meeting in db.tbl_meetings on election.fk_meeting_id equals meeting.meeting_id 
join election in db.tbl_elections on round.fk_election_id equals election.election_id 
select round;
```

The error I'm getting is that the name 'election' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: looks like you have the order wrong -- put the election join first

Comment: both answers correct

Comment: yeah getting two good answers happens a lot on SO -- I like to upvote both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to re-order the join statement probably like

```
from round in db.tbl_rounds
join election in db.tbl_elections on round.fk_election_id equals election.election_id
join meeting in db.tbl_meetings on election.fk_meeting_id equals meeting.meeting_id  
select round;
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you have "election" used before it is declared.

```
from round in db.tbl_rounds
join meeting in db.tbl_meetings on -->election<--.fk_meeting_id equals meeting.meeting_id 
join -->election<-- in db.tbl_elections on round.fk_election_id equals election.election_id 
select round;
```

In this case, you will need to change order in your query.

Query should look like this:

```
from round in db.tbl_rounds
join election in db.tbl_elections on round.fk_election_id equals election.election_id
join meeting in db.tbl_meetings on election.fk_meeting_id equals meeting.meeting_id 
select round;
```